# How to trigger a Modal window with jquery function?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a button with some validation function written in click event of jquery, which needs to trigger a modal window on successful validation.I have placed my modal trigger function within an IF condition which is not triggering my modal window. Can you please help me to find the issue and solve.

**Note**: when placing my modal trigger function on the very first line within the document.ready function the same modal window works, but not triggering when placed in click function.

Header and html code of modal

```
         <head>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
         </head>

                   <div id="submit_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

jquery code for click function

```
   $(".subdomain_check").click(function(){
    var form = $("#msform");
    form.validate();
    if(form.valid() === true){     
     var doamin_check = $("#subdomain_input").val();
      if (doamin_check == '' ) {
       $("#subdomain_available").text("");
       $("#subdomain_error").text("Please Enter a domain name");
       return false;
        }
      else {
      $("#submit_modal").modal('show');  // Modal triger function
       
      $("#subdomain_error").text("");
      $("#subdomain_available").text("Domain Available");

     current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
       }
      }        
             });
```

Comment: can you create demo code ?